# Downvote on specific topics within 1 minute

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have received downvotes on my Stack Overflow Qt questions. As those downvotes are all within 1 minute, I doubt they are justified. Strange, they only cover my Qt questions, not the latest.

How could that happen?[image: downvotes]

Comment: Those votes are cast so close to each other (in time)  I'm pretty confident this gets caught by the voting-reversal script at 03:00 UTC. If this pattern gets repeated for the next few days, do raise a mod flag on one of your posts for a moderator to look at.

Comment: Sorry you got hit with this, and you weren't the only one. The user responsible will not be doing this for a while. The system should invalidate all of these votes within 24 hours. If it doesn't, flag us and we'll have them manually removed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it looks like you are indeed "under attack" from a particular user.

You're not the first and there are scripts that run which will weed out this behaviour. (When this has happened to me, the voting has been reversed after about a day.)

Be assured, your reputation will be restored.

(As a rule of thumb, don't vote on any page that's been reached from inspecting a user profile.)

Comment: Just for myself, what is the purpose of such an attack. Is there any logic behind that? I mean SPAM normally serves a purpose, I am to stupid to see benefit in downvoting on SO.

Comment: @HorstWalter: My guess is that a user has lost their temper. And there is no logic in any behaviour emanating from a loss of control.